# under what conditions the following matrix optimization has a unique solution?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

So the problem is simple:

Consider the following matrix optimization problem on matrix D. What conditions on the matrix dimensions should apply so that the solution to the minimum is unique. please note that D $\in R^{n\times n}$ is square and $M\in R^{m\times n}$. and $a$ and $b$ are simply vectors of length $n$ and $m$ respectively.

Here is the optimization :

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
& ~~~~~~~~ \underset{D}{\text{min}}
& & \|b-MD a\|_2 \\
& \text{subject to:} & &  \\
& & & \|D\|_2<1.\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

My comments: I think if $n>m^2$ then it has a unique solution (minimizer) because that means we have basically $m^2$ variables to solve with n equations. so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated, the problem might have no solutions at all. If the constraint would be replaced by $\|D\|\le 1$ then there is at least one solution.

If $n>1$ then the problem never has a unique solution.

Let $D_1$ be such at solution. Then there are plenty other matrices $D$ such that $Da = D_1a$ and $\|D\|\le1$, hence $D$ is also a solution.

Hence, the answer to the question is: The problem is uniquely solvable, if the constraint set is $\|D\|\le 1$, $n=1$, $M\ne 0$, $a\ne0$.

Comment: I didn't get your first statement: if you replace strict inequality, why is it so?

Comment: Then the set of feasible points is compact.

Comment: @ehsank, to clarify: the problem is guaranteed to have an optimal *value*, but not an optimal *point*. That is, there is no $D$ satisfying $\|D\|<1$ that actually achieves the optimal value---you will be able to get arbitrarily close, but as you get closer, $\|D\|$ will approach 1, so you can never actually get there.  If you relax the problem to $\|D\|\leq 1$, *then* you can guarantee the existence of a solution.

Comment: @MichaelGrant thanks now it's clear. But if it has several solutions for n>1 then how the solvers only one solution?

Comment: @ehsank I am afraid I don't understand the question.

Comment: sorry some words were missing, I mean why then optimization solvers only return one solution. how should it be decided which solution is the best.

Comment: Because it is not practical for a solver to return more than one; because different algorithms approach the optimal set in different ways. From the user's perspective the choice is arbitrary. If the user has a *preference* among the optimal points then that indicates that the model was incomplete in the first place.